# Как сделать страницу портфолио на wordpress, если страница блога уже есть?

Tags: wordpress

Как сделать страницу портфолио на wordpress, если страница блога уже есть?
Хочу сделать похожее портфолио https://apelsun.ua/portfolio.html
но вот как можно это сделать с иерархией вордпресс, если уже есть страница с блогом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте для этих целей `register_post_type` и создайте нужный пост тип.

```
add_action('init', 'my_custom_init');
function my_custom_init(){
    register_post_type('portfolio', array(
        'labels'             => array(
            'name'               => 'Книги', // Основное название типа записи
            'singular_name'      => 'Книга', // отдельное название записи типа Book
            'add_new'            => 'Добавить новую',
            'add_new_item'       => 'Добавить новую книгу',
            'edit_item'          => 'Редактировать книгу',
            'new_item'           => 'Новая книга',
            'view_item'          => 'Посмотреть книгу',
            'search_items'       => 'Найти книгу',
            'not_found'          =>  'Книг не найдено',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'В корзине книг не найдено',
            'parent_item_colon'  => '',
            'menu_name'          => 'Книги'

          ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => true,
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array('title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','comments')
    ) );
}
```

https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_post_type

Comment: Можете объяснить своими словами как это будет работать, пожалуйста?

Comment: Создаете пост тип portfolio. Создаете в теме файл single-portfolio.php и работаете как с обычным постом